# How to have Gmail receiving email for an account in another domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, gmail

I have my own domain and also a Gmail account. I would like to have all the emails sent to my domain's email address redirected to my Gmail account; that is, I want all the emails sent to `myname@mydomain.com` to be received on my Gmail account instead, as if they had been sent to `myname@gmail.com`

I have configured my domain's DNS records to point to Gmail's mail server, [as explained in Gmail documentation](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33915). However, when I send a message to `myname@mydomain.com` I receive an error message saying that:

> mx.google.com rejected your message to the following e-mail addresses:
>
> myname@mydomain.com
>
> The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
>   double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary
>   spaces.

I have `myname@mydomain.com` configured as an alternate "From" address to send emails in Gmail, otherwise I can't find any related configuration parameter in Gmail itself.

So, the question is: how should I configure my domain's DNS records and/or my Gmail account to accept emails sent to `myname@mydomain.com`? I know it is possible since I have done it in the past, I just can't remember how. Thank you!

Comment: You need a Google Apps account to do this.

Comment: This is not a serverfault question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Have google apps panel and link `mydomain.com` there, verify its ownership and activate Google Mail service on `mydomain.com`
2. Once done! create a new email account `myname@mydomain.com` and forward all incoming mails to `myname@gmail.com`

Most probably `mx.google.com` is rejecting mails due to unverified domain name `mydomain.com` and no linked Google Mail service.

Comment: So, do I need a Google Apps account? I did the same thing in the past by just configuring the DNS records on my domain provider. I wonder how I did it?

Comment: See, there are Domain Providers who provide an option to enable Google Mail service from their panels itself for the said domain like Name.com. Confirm with your Domain Provider and if not so, sign-up with Google Apps.

Comment: Ended up configuring a simple email forwarding in my service provider, as using Google Apps is not an option for me. Thank you anyway!